# A difficulty in understanding the proof of theorem 4.1 in chapter3 in Israel Gohberg.

Tags: operator-theory, proof-explanation

The proof is given in the following pictures:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Could not calculate the details of how equation(1) come, could anyone help me in doing so please?

Comment: What does Theorem I.3.1 say?

Comment: It says the parallelogram law@MatthewLeingang

Comment: I know that.  I'm saying copying out the parallelogram law might be useful in understanding the details of how equation (1) comes about.

Comment: $|| x +y || ^2 + ||x-y|^2 = 2(||x||^2 + ||y||^2)|$ for every x,y in an inner product space $E$. @MatthewLeingang

Comment: Ok I will do @MatthewLeingang but how m enters?

Comment: That is the other part of that sentence between the two equations: the definition of $m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the old multiply-and-divide-the-same thing trick:
$$
    \left<A(x+y),x+y\right>
   =\left<A\left(\frac{x+y}{\Vert x+y\Vert}\right),\frac{x+y}{\Vert x+y\Vert}\right>\Vert x+y\Vert^2
$$
The inner product is of the form $\left<Au,u\right>$ with $\Vert u \Vert =1$, so it's $\leq m$.  So
$$
    \left<A(x+y),x+y\right> \leq m \Vert x+y\Vert^2
$$
Similarly,
$$
    \left<A(x-y),x-y\right> \leq m \Vert x-y\Vert^2
$$
Add them together and use the parallelogram law.